# Changing Signing Team on .xcarchive

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I would like to change the signing team for one of my old iOS app build. I have `.xarchieve` file and able to change the bundle identifier and version successfully. But I am not sure how to change the Signing Team. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: seems you are planning to resign the application with different cert and different provisioning profile.. am I right?

Comment: Yes I am. I have changed the bundle identifier and associated certificate but since the team is not changed I am unable to extract the ipa file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can resign the xcarchive file using the [iReSign](https://github.com/maciekish/iReSign) application in Git Hub. I tried it and worked without any issues. You need to additionally provide a path to entitlement plist file. Update the entitlement plist file according to your new cert. Hope this will work